# SQL(BigQuery) Join two tables with lag() function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Considering I have a two tables.

First one:

| user_id | name | timestamp1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | purchase | 12 |
| 1 | purchase | 14 |
| 2 | purchase | 22 |
| 2 | purchase | 14 |

Second one:

| user_id | event_name | timestamp2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | event1 | 10 |
| 1 | event2 | 11 |
| 2 | event12 | 20 |
| 2 | event10 | 12 |

A want to add to the table one some fields(event_name, timestamp2) from the table two  with the  closest previous values by user_id, order by timestamp for every event from table one

Desired table should look like this

| user_id | name | timestamp1 | event_name | timestamp2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | purchase | 12 | event2 | 11 |
| 1 | purchase | 14 | event2 | 11 |
| 2 | purchase | 22 | event12 | 20 |
| 2 | purchase | 14 | event10 | 12 |

Help me please with sql query!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join on `user_id` then using `row_number()` ordered by the distance between `timestamp1` and `timestamp2` to get the closest row from table2:

```
SELECT  user_id, name, timestamp1, event_name, timestamp2
FROM (
  SELECT    t1.*, t2.event_name, t2.timestamp2,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.user_id, t1.timestamp1 ORDER BY ABS(t1.timestamp1 - t2.timestamp2)) AS rn
  FROM      table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON        t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
select any_value(t1).*, 
  array_agg(struct(event_name,timestamp2) order by timestamp2 desc limit 1)[offset(0)].*
from `project.dataset.table1` t1 
cross join `project.dataset.table2` t2
where t2.user_id = t1.user_id and timestamp2 < timestamp1
group by format('%t', t1)
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]